# How to convert a Yii2 local website to a desktop executable?

Tags: linux, windows, web, yii2, desktop-application

I currently have a local basic Yii2 website with an external database on XAMPP. Is there a way I could convert this application to a native desktop application that can run on Windows and the Linux OS?

I wish to build the desktop app myself and not use automatic builders like [Web2Desk](https://appmaker.xyz/web2desk/)

It'll come as an .exe file which can be run to install the app. The app would not need any 3rd-party software (for the database for example). I'm thinking kind of like the Slack desktop application.

Can you please help?

Comment: Probably Electron is the target to learn: https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly do you mean that you don't want to use "automatic builders" but to run PHP website you basically need 3 things. A browser that can display site written in HTML/CSS/JS and send request to server. A server that can handle incoming requests and return proper response. And a PHP interpreter that can run php scripts for server and generate proper response. So, to run PHP website as desktop app you have to find a tool that will pack those three things plus your code into single package.

Comment: @MichalHynčica yes, that's exactly what I'm asking. Is there a tool that can do all 3 and render the site as a desktop application